# Google Developers API AndroidPublisher: BundleListResponse doesn't return all Bundles

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, androidpublisher

I'm trying to pull a list of all bundles uploaded to the Google Play console for a specific app.

I'm sending a Get request to "https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/#bundle_id/edits/#edit/bundles"

And I receive a proper response as describe in [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.bundles/list). However the response list of bundles contains only 7 entries, while when I open the Play Console in the browser I see more than 100 bundles.

Here is the code I use in ruby but the language shouldn't really matter and the respective output:

**Code:**

```
response = Google::Mobile::API::Developers::Request.send(
    url: "https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/#{bundle_id}/edits/#{edit["id"]}/bundles", 
    method: "get", 
     headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}"})
                        
pp response
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "kind"=>"androidpublisher#bundlesListResponse",
  "bundles"=>[
    {"versionCode"=>1686048804, "sha1"=>"38103404ee82d6df6afad7bebd199503f53b114c", "sha256"=>"4265cfcf3f31fba23053a6d2c374efcd8f16437dce313fbf63cd4275becedf5e"},
    {"versionCode"=>1695127000, "sha1"=>"3d6db7520af917c670dc701ad572e3051b0075be", "sha256"=>"182c52de5d17b925d8b3ec6b8774ed878d2565b8bbbde952f06f9c7e8f3efbb2"},
    {"versionCode"=>1696238537, "sha1"=>"94bec66e32b071fadcbb5fba6b4e3399984e932a", "sha256"=>"bf3228f41a176ee74e326b760f31c9e9911fbf57605182415d5ec01c41f54ed8"},
    {"versionCode"=>1696244888, "sha1"=>"f58b3beeede792d876990b8a4c053c58a1280436", "sha256"=>"3b6369eb49fc42f3090e2602d00f48ce3236cfeb65a94d293b5103638fc4761a"},
    {"versionCode"=>1696246304, "sha1"=>"8bc65e39e15e6b9649e4743916e118e3fcc42c8e", "sha256"=>"0dac53e89c1839af96721ce0e95dd824cf44835eed99188ed6fc2d01a36fd343"},
    {"versionCode"=>1696254659, "sha1"=>"3d8775851f86f11d33b496bdf03759df5b12cb31", "sha256"=>"99c7cd964b698c8231b15ef34528727e68ccc2367a3cf7c2708ea0c3f8165dee"},
    {"versionCode"=>1696266738, "sha1"=>"5bacb47bfb6fcfa83eac7e40ca95d09113a1ea64", "sha256"=>"e8f707c8bf004a4e8d6236bc6d0176018af578e4e25b3215b1b8ffe1c3593485"}
  ]
}
```

Here is a picture of how this looks in the browser

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?